# void operation requires 'produces' swagger definition in assertj-swagger

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, swagger-2.0, springfox, assertj

I have the following Spring Boot (1.3.1) `@RestController` defined:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/blah", method = DELETE)
@ResponseStatus(NO_CONTENT)
public void blah() {...}
```

and am using [`assertj-swagger`](https://github.com/RobWin/assertj-swagger) to validate the above against the following swagger specification:

```
'/blah':
  delete:
```

Validation (assertion) of the implemented operation fails for the following reason:

```
[Checking 'produces' of 'DELETE' operation of path '/blah'] 
 Expecting null or empty but was:<["*/*"]>
```

But I can't understand why a `produces` `MediaType.ALL` is required when it's a `void` method we're attempting to describe with Swagger?

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated, seems extraneous to have to add this to all of our documented APIs...

Thanks and regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Http is [a request/response protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Technical_overview). So even if your operation returns a void, there is still a http response; even if it has a `Content-Length` of 0 (void). Thats the reason its modeled as a `MediaType.ALL` (read any media type or no particular media type)

Comment: Hmmm, thanks, I can see your point Dilip, I guess maybe I'm arguing with the Swagger spec (?) as really can't see the point in having to document what is essentially boilerplate? But technically that'd be correct...